# Convert string to number while sending data

Tags: react-native

When I am submitting a data without any edit I am able to submit it, but when I am editing a value I am not able to submit the data because I am sending the value in string, during edit I have to convert the value to number, so I want to know how can I do this as I am not able to solve the issue, please let me now how can I solve this issue

Comment: show your codes please, else how are we going to correct your errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

**Note** : you must be sure the string actually contain the number(I mean it should be convert-able value)

```
let stringData = "2020";

const num = Number(stringData);
console.log(num);
```